# Swift Software caused connection abort after backgrounding app

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, urlsession

I am developing an app that consumes soap services.

I implemented a functionality that may mean that the app goes to background. My problem is that, **sometimes**, when the app gets to the foreground again, I get the error "Software caused connection to abort".

Previously I had the "Socket is not connected" error as well, however I fixed it by creating my sessions when I'm invoking a web service as follows:

```
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
config.waitsForConnectivity = true
config.shouldUseExtendedBackgroundIdleMode = true
let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
```

I set the `waitsForConnectivity` and `shouldUseExtendedBackgroundIdleMode` properties to true, as an attempt to fix this error, but it did not work.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: We encounterd the same issue, have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44624199/software-caused-connection-abort-error-returned-in-replyconnection-invalid